# Understanding heatflow, minisplit vs. open stairwell

Tags: heat-pump, heat, mini-split

Still getting used to the minisplit heat-pump HVAC (well, HAC) system I put in a few years ago, along with improving the house's insulation.

One of the differences I'm noticing from when I was heating with forced-hot-water radiators is that I seem to be seeing a lot more heat traveling up the stairwell. The upstairs rooms, despite having more exposure, seem to want to settle at several degrees above the downstairs rooms, even when their heat-pump heads are set for lower temperatures. With the radiators I was able to run the upstairs bedrooms several degrees cooler than downstairs.

Yes, I'm sure I can mostly solve this by being better about closing the doors on the upstairs corridor. And I've played a bit with using a stand-alone fan and duct as a homebrew "return" to bring heat from upstairs back downstairs.

But I'd like to understand what's the probable cause of the difference in heating behavior between the two systems and/or due to the improved insulation, and what I should be doing in the way of tuning the system to balance the two floors for best efficiency.

Comment: Just a comment, as I hope someone much more experience with HVAC can answer. But my hunch is *air flow*. Hot water radiators are providing heat by radiation. Heat pumps are using convection - air is heated, the air is *forced* around the room and some of it heads up the stairs.

Comment: I figured that might be part of the equation. Also, in the radiator system, there is actually a radiator at the base of the stairs, which may be creating its own circulation zone. But if I can get input from someone who actually knows this stuff, that'd be helpful. If not, I'll continue to experiment. I still mostly like the system, but this is defeating my old approach of "set the upstairs bedroom cooler and use more blankets".

Comment: Most hot water "radiators" are more passive convectors than radiators, really. But they **are** distributed more widely than heat pump heads (usually - heat pump heads are expensive) and they are placed low as they are for heating only. Warm air rises in any case. Closing doors to prevent air flow is the likeliest solution. I heat with a pair of heat pumps, one up, one down, and I set the down one a bit cooler because otherwise it's doing all the work most of the time. In "shoulder seasons" I don't even turn the upstairs one on, or only run the fan in it to circulate/filter air.

Answer (score 1):

A mini-split system includes a fan, because when you reverse the heat pump to cool the room, you have to blow air over the coils to prevent humidity from collecting into water and then freezing.

That fan moves the air, and will be used even in the heating cycle, to better move the heat off the coil into the room.  Your radiator lacked such a fan.

With the additional air movement, odds are that your heated air is getting blown out of the room, and the radiator didn't have the same issue as you didn't have a fan blowing across it.

Comment: I suspected that might be a contributing factor, and was wondering whether using the left/right vanes to direct circulation one way or the other around the central area might have an effect. I think @Ecnerwal's suggestions may be more directly applicable, but if that doesn't help enough this gives me another set of ideas to play with. Good: This system has lots of adjustments for fine-tuning. Bad: This system has lots of adjustments to get wrong. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the vane direction on the heat pump heads either down or oscillating/sweeping for heating season? Most (not all) heat pump heads are located high on the wall for A/C and to be out of the way, and need the vanes pointing down to get warm air down lower and force-circulate the room in heating season. Most radiator systems, particularly "baseboard" types are already located low on outside walls and set up air circulation up the wall, across the ceiling, down the opposite wall and across the floor by simple convection (hot air rising up the wall from the radiator, pulling cooler air into the radiator from the floor, etc.)

If your vanes are set high (as for cooling) the warm air produced will tend to stay high, and then find its way up the stairs to go higher.

In any case, you probably (virtually certainly) have far fewer linear feet of heat pump head vent delivering heat than you did radiators, so the heat delivery is more concentrated rather than widely distributed, until the fans get air circulating by force. Closing doors either up or downstairs (which will depend on room layout and heat pump location) is almost certainly the only way you'll be able fight the natural tendency for warm air to make it to the top of the house.

Likewise, a hot-water system is working to satisfy a thermostat away from the radiators (usually in the middle of the house) while mini-splits almost universally are controlling the temperature **measured at the mini-split head** which is typically several feet above where a thermostat for a central system would be located, and usually on an outside wall. The temperature where you are can vary quite a bit form the temperature at the heat pump head., to a greater degree than is typical for a central thermostat.

Comment: Measured at the mini-split head -- Yeah, discovered that; it makes setting the temperature a bit odd since I I need to set the number at the head rather than in the room. I'm working on some home automation to take over that control and use room-temperature measurements instead, to get behavior more like a traditional hydronic system.

Comment: Downstairs is open plan, so unless I put in more doors (which I'd rather not) closing the upstairs doors is the better bet. Though I'm experimenting with a fan near the upstairs ceiling blowing into a duct draped down the stairs.

Comment: The Mitsubishi system is supposed to be able to "intelligently" set the vanes up or down depending on whether it's in heating or cooling mode. But it can also be set manually, and I can point it downward farther than the automatic setting has it, or put it in sweep mode. Thanks; that's a good set of experiments.